# How to change Show/Remove Dialog and onPrepareDialog for DialogFragments

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments

I'm working on an Android project. I need to use Android 1.6 or above.

My project was working, but now it is showing me some warnings about Dialogs like

```
"The method dismissDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated"
"The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated", etc.
```

So I want to "update" my project to solve these warnings.

I have read and made some test projects to learn about Fragments and DialogFragment.
I have created my own ProgressDialog and I want to use it on my real project, but I have some problems.

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends DialogFragment {

public MyProgressDialog(){

}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Context context = getActivity();

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

        String message = resources.getText(R.string.wait).toString();

    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

    return dialog;
    }
}
```

Earlier in my project, I created the `ProgressDialog` and then, in `onPrepareDialog()` method, I called an `AsyncTask` to connect the server, downloaded the data, etc. Then in `onPostExecute` of the AsyncTask, I dismissed the `ProgressDialog` and started the new Activity. But now I can't do that because `onPrepareDialog` is deprecated.

**Calling ActionAsyncTask on onPrepareDialog of Activy**

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {     
    switch(id){

        case Constants.PROGRESS_DIALOG:
                                    new ActionAsyncTask().execute();
                                    break;
    }
}
```

**onPostExecute of ActionAsyncTask**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    dismissDialog(Constants.PROGRESS_DIALOG);
}
```

How can solve this? What is the right way to do this? I want to write the best code for this, the most efficient code.

Thanks.